# Endfloat without Captions below Figures

Tags: floats, captions, endfloat

I want my figures at the end of my document with separate captions. For this I thought the `endfloat` package might be useful. However it prints the captions in a list of figures (this is what I want) but the captions again below the figures. Can I turn off the captions below the figures but keep the captions in my list of figures?

My current `endfloat` configuration is: `\usepackage[nomarkers,figuresonly]{endfloat}`.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "separate captions". Separate from what? And, how are readers supposed to be able to associate entries in the List of Figures, say, "Figure 3", if the corresponding `figure` environments don't exhibit captions? Do you expect them to wade through the figures until they find one that "looks right"?

Comment: @Mico Separate from the figure. I see that it might be not possible since the label "Figure X" is also part of the caption. So I thought it would be possible to have the captions in the figure list and then only the figures with "Fig.1", "Fig.2" without the long description below them.

Comment: It sounds like you want "long descriptions" in the list of figures, but not in the immediate vicinity of the figures. Shouldn't it be the other way round?

Comment: @Mico What do you mean with other way round? The problem is that some captions are so long that either the figures need to be very small or the caption exceeds the page. I thought this solution would be the simplest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the caption only in the list of figure, use the optional argument of `\caption`, and let its mandatory one empty.

I use the `caption` package to format the label.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelsep=none]{caption}
\usepackage[nomarkers,figuresonly]{endfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption[short text]{}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{figure}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```